# CSS two and more objects independent animations (rotate+scale)

Tags: html, css, animation, transform, scale

Please help a newbie with this example
Each picture must be scaled and rotated independently of the other, relative to its center at the given coordinates on the page.
The scaling animation is repeated 1 time, the rotation animation is infinite.

Can I animate the second picture with a delay after the first?
Can all this be done in pure CSS?

```css
.image {
    -webkit-animation: scale 4s 1 linear;    
}

.spinner {
      -webkit-animation: spin 8s infinite linear;
}


@-webkit-keyframes spin { 
  0% { 
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    } 
    100% { 
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    } 
}
@-webkit-keyframes scale {
   0% {
         transform: scaleX(0) scaleY(0);
    }
}
    100% {
         transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner" style="position: absolute; top: 20%; left: 30%;">
<img class="image" src="http://makeameme.org/media/templates/120/grumpy_cat.jpg" >
</div>

<div class="spinner" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;">
<img class="image" src="http://makeameme.org/media/templates/120/rainbow-spongbob.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstand. Have you tried the animation-delay property?

Comment: You have not closed divs </div> hense the bob is nested inside cat container.

Comment: oh my, such a dumb mistake. Many thanks sir, fixed

Comment: @azizarslan, yep animation-delay works fine (not used in the example) separately for animation of scaling and rotation, but the combined animation (scaling + rotation) runs simultaneously for both pictures. Can the combined animation of the second picture be run a short time after the first? I think i need to use different keyframes or different animations for two different pictures.

Comment: @WallabeBeatles You don't need to use separate animations. Just define different animation-delay to the relevant elements.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to set :

```
.image:nth-child(n) {
    animation-delay: 5s;
}
.image:nth-child(n+1) {
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
```

Change the delay as you want and set anothers ones by changing every time the nth-child() by n+2, n+3, n+4.
Is that what you wanted ?